# Using RoboSpice/Retrofit with Parametrized types for JSON Response

Tags: java, android, json, generics, retrofit

Help please T_T been digging for 2 days for a solution to this problem!

I am using Retrofit to make some networking tasks in my app,
One of the APIs that I am calling returns a different object sometimes, but i know when and what it will return everytime I call it.

In this case the `Message` is an object

```
{
  "key": "some key",
  "category": "some category",
  "channel": "some channel",
  "status": "some status",
  "message": {
    "someValue": "54",
    "someOtherValue": "5353"
  }
}
```

and here the `Message` is a string

```
{
  "key": "some key",
  "category": "some category",
  "channel": "some channel",
  "status": "some status",
  "message": "this is a string"
}
```

so I am trying to achieve a good design of this solution by using generics, 
I have a generic class like this,

**ContentResponse Class**

```
public class ContentResponse<T> {

private List<Content<T>> content = new ArrayList<Content<T>>();

//getters and setters
}
```

**Content Class**

```
public class Content<T>
{
    private String key;
    private String category;
    private String channel;
    private String status;
    private T message;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**ContentInterface Class**

```
public interface ContentInterface<T>
{
    @GET("/public/content/{category}")
    ContentResponse<T> getContent(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);
}
```

The issue lies here

```
public class ContentRequest<T> extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<ContentResponse<T>, ContentInterface<T>>
        {
        String category;

        public ContentRequest(Class<ContentResponse<T>> clazz, Class<ContentInterface<T>> retrofittedInterfaceClass, String category) {
            super(clazz, retrofittedInterfaceClass);
            this.category = category;
        }


        @Override
        public ContentResponse<T> loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
            return getService().getContent(category);
        }
    }
```

In this context i know that the object returned is a `Map<String, String>`

```
    contentRequest = new ContentRequest(new Class<ContentResponse<Map<String, String>>>(),
new Class<ContentInterface<Map<String, String>>>(),
"appstrings");
```

but i get this !!

> 'class()' is not public in java.lang.Class

I cant just call `ContentResponse<Map<String,String>>.class`, so what can I do here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in Retrofit

```
public interface ContentInterface<T>
{
    @GET("/public/content/{category}")
    ContentResponse<T> getContent(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);
}
```

Retrofit uses the signature of the method at runtime to determine the return `Type`.  In this case it would be a raw `Class` of `ContentResponse` and with a `ParameterizedType` of `T` which obviously wouldn't work.

The way to make this work is to add the `ParameterizedType` in the interface like so.
EDIT: Notice how the `ContentInterface` is no longer typed with `T`

```
public interface ContentInterface
{
    @GET("/public/content/{category}")
    ContentResponse<String> getContent(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);
}
```

But then that defeats the purpose because you can't have 2 method definition which has the same signature.  This won't compile because of type erasure.

```
public interface ContentInterface
{
    @GET("/public/content/{category}")
    ContentResponse<String> getContent(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);

    ContentResponse<Map<String, String> getContent(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);
}
```

So in the end you'd still need to create 2 different methods to interact with the 2 different type of data.

```
public interface ContentInterface
{
    @GET("/public/content/{category}")
    ContentResponse<String> getContentAsString(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);

    ContentResponse<Map<String, String> getContentAsMap(@Path(PathParameters.CATEGORY) String category);
}
```

See @JakeWharton response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400897/any-way-to-have-generic-url-using-retrofit?answertab=votes#tab-top) about generalization with Retrofit and why they don't really support it.  I believe the same idea applies to this.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer :)
so I will create multiple methods for each type of response, but how would I get the type of the parameterized 'ContentResponse' for my ContentRequest ?

Comment: Since the ContentInterface interface doesn't use type `T` anymore you can simply pass ContentInterface.class.   

`contentRequest = new ContentRequest(/*not sure how this is used*/, ContentInterface.class, "appstrings");`

Comment: You are right, but the ContentRequest takes the 2 params (Class<T> responseType, Class<R> retrofitInterface), the first param is the expected response type, what should I pass in case when I am expecting ContentResponse<Map<String,String>> ?

Comment: I'm not sure how your `RetrofitSpiceRequest` is implemented but passing the class of the response will not work.  Basically now you need to have 2 `loadDataFromNetwork` methods.  One for `ContentResponse<String>` and one for `ContentResponse<Map<String,String>>`.

Comment: After all this time, I decided to ditch robospice & started digging into Retrofit with RxJava :)